# LINQ VB.Net variable not declared error

Tags: vb.net, linq

I am trying to run this line of code:

```
Dim OrderedFiles() As String = Directory.GetFiles(FilePath).OrderBy(x >= x.CreationTime)
```

I get an error on x saying x is not declared.

I have my project set to Option Strict Off and Option Infer On. If I turn ON Option Strict then I get thousands of errors from the project(it is inherited) and I don't have the time to fix all of them, but x no longer gives me an error. I have googled until I want to throw my computer out the window.

Any help on how to correct this statement would be appreciated.

Edit:

I was hoping for a more elegant solution but here is what I came up with to solve this particular problem.

```
    Dim fileList() As String = Directory.GetFiles(FilePath)
    Dim fileDate(fileList.Length - 1) As DateTime

    For i As Integer = 0 To fileList.Length - 1
        fileDate(i) = New FileInfo(fileList(i)).CreationTime
    Next

    Array.Sort(fileDate, fileList)

    With EmailTemplates_DropDownList
        .DataSource = fileList.Reverse.Take(5)
        .DataBind()
    End With
```

It is not particularly elegant but it does the job. I was hoping for a one liner LINQ solution and I just don't have the background in LINQ to know how to do the job, time to go buy a book.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure where you got this syntax from:

```
OrderBy(x >= x.CreationTime)
```

That *almost* looks like the C# syntax of

```
OrderBy(x => x.CreationTime)
```

but I believe in VB you would use

```
OrderBy(Function(x) x.CreationTime)
```

That's certainly what the example in [`Enumerable.OrderBy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534966.aspx#Y1036) would suggest.

EDIT: At that point you'll get a different error, as per Steve's post... but he hasn't corrected the syntax. I suspect you want:

```
Dim OrderedFiles() As FileInfo = new DirectoryInfo(FilePath).GetFiles(). 
                                        OrderBy(Function(x) x.CreationTime).
                                        ToArray()
```

Comment: @Steve: "doesn't work" isn't a very helpful description of the error. I'm off to bed now, but please provide more information in future.

Comment: Is there a LINQPad version for VB.net? All the examples and books I can find are in C#, which I don't want to learn and trying to convert examples into vb is a pain.

Comment: @JonSkeet Right, just testing now on linqpad and gives out `Impossible to convert the value of type 'System.Linq.IOrderedEnumerable(Of System.IO.FileInfo)' in 'Matrix 1 dimension of String.'.` (Just a rought translation from Italian)

Comment: @Varuuknahl the current version of linqpad allow also VB.Net syntax

Comment: @JonSkeet got it. Was the OrderedFiles as **String**

Comment: @Steve: I hadn't noticed that you weren't the OP when I replied, which puts rather less onus on you to provide more information - but it's still better to give what the error is. Will edit...

Answer (score 2):

Directory.GetFiles() returns the names of files (including their paths) in the specified directory.
It's not possible to use x.CreationTime, x is a string

Probably you should use DirectoryInfo

```
Dim di as DirectoryInfo = new DirectoryInfo(FilePath)
Dim OrderedFiles = di.GetFiles().OrderBy(Function(x) x.CreationTime).Take(3)
Dim fi as FileInfo
For each fi in OrderedFiles
    Console.WriteLine(fi.FullName)
Next
```

Comment: I tried using this method but I need the path information. Is there no way to sort the Directory.GetFiles by CreationTime, without going through multiple arrays, worse yet I only need that last, n number of files created. I gave up trying to get Take(n) to work.

Comment: I also tried: Dim eFileList = (From File In Directory.EnumerateFiles(FilePath) Order By File.CreationTime).Take(3), but as you said I get the CreationTime is not a member of string.

Comment: Updated answer. You get back an ordered collection of FileInfo, here you have the FullName and the DirectoryName property